# What is the amortized cost of a sequence of n insertion in a binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, amortized-analysis

How do I calculate the amortized cost of a sequence of **n** insertions in a binary search tree? The input sequence is random and each insert adds one node.

Comment: @jozefg no the tree in not self balancing basic Binary search tree

Comment: @jozefg but is this analysis is tight enough. We dont know will be the input sequence. IF it produce a balance tree then each insertion will take O(lgn) time. For n insertion n*O(logn). So, the amortized cost per operation become n*O(logn)/n = O(lgn). Is it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to be able to analyze the time for a single operation and average it over a sequence of operations. We can follow the technique of amortized analysis.

**Definition 1**

Suppose we have a data structure that supports certain operations. Let `T (n)` be the worst-case time for performing any sequence of `n` such operations on this data structure. Then the amortized time per operation is defined as `T(n)/n.` ([source](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/lecturenotes/amortized.pdf))

Since, you have a Binary search tree, this means that in the worst case scenario you will have a linked-list (all element on the left or all element on the right).

If you have `n` insertion operation `T(n) = 1+2+...n = (n * (n-1)) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2.`

By the Definition 1 amortized time per operation = (n - 1) / 2.  O(n)

Maybe I am interpreting it wrong, so please comment if you think so.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can expect to generate a roughly-balanced binary tree for a random sequence of insertions, implying an average node height proportional to log(n) (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree) for explanation). Amortized time = total time / number of operations. The total time is equal to average height * number of elements, or O(n * log(n)). Since the total time is O(n * log(n)), the amortized time is O(log(n)).

Comment: I believe an amortized analysis guarantees the average performance
of each operation in the worst case..........but may be you are not taking the worst case scenario.

Comment: Amortized time usually implies the average-case scenario (especially since "random sequence" is specified in the question).

Comment: You are not making confusion with Splay_tree ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree